# on-prem sybase to aws aurora

Tags: sybase, aws-aurora

I want to migrate from on-Prem Sybase to AWS Aurora Postgres database. I came across tools like AWS SCT and AWS DMS, but I am not sure , if the source Sybase database should be in AWS cloud as a pre-requisite for the AWS tools to initiate the migration.

What are the other options we have in case we want to migrate from On-Prem Sybase to AWS Aurora Postgres database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, the answer is in the documentation: 'You can use AWS SCT to  replicate the data to either S3 or Snowflake' https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_DMSIntegration.html which would be cheaper as AWS tend to charge for data being transported in/out of the AWS Cloud.

For the second question there are several other options, which essentially involves you building your own ETL or migration utilities.